# How to make destructor-friendly call to exec() in C++?

Tags: c++, exec, destructor

I have tried to run c-style function `exec()` (with some suffix) in a C++ code, but mentioned that no destructors were invoked for existing objects.

Is there a way to guarantee the invokation of all required destructors - like on the program termination - before the `exec()`?

May be, there is another way to achieve the substitution of executing code without `exec()` in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the man page

> The exec() functions only returns if an error has occurred.

Since the exec function overlays the process with a new image, there is no way that you can perform any destructors after a successull call.

If you need to clean up, then you should do it before exec is called.